# Showing Iteration in GUI

Tags: matlab, iteration, matlab-guide

I'm working with k-means in MATLAB GUI. I want to show the iterations of the process on the GUI when they press the push button. But I am not able to do this. I only can do this by command window--and all of us can.

Here is the snippet of the iteration process:

> c(i,:)=mean(data(find(g==i),:),1)

It can only be shown on command window. I added this line to show the iteration process on GUI, but it's not working:

> CCC = mean(data(find(g==i),:),1);
>  t=uitable;
>  set(t,'Data',CCC)

What shall I do to show the iteration on GUI?

I appreciate all the answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `drawnow`command after you set the data in `t`. See the documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html